# How do C++ Vectors not overwrite within memory space with default constructor?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, theory

This is more of a theoretical question than a problem.

To my understanding std::vector will dynamically resize/reallocate memory when adding, removing, or constructing.

I have a few questions about how vectors work at the lowest level, using the code example below

1. What is preventing the following example from overwriting the memory space of `string1`?
2. Are vectors contiguous in the same way as arrays?
3. If there is a total memory available that a vector requires, but it is not contiguous, will it de-fragment the memory space?

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string string1 = "Some really large string";  

    /* A bunch of other random declarations take place 
    ...
    */

    vector<int> vector1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       vector1.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: One question per question please Cody

Comment: I don't understand why you expect an operating system to allocate memory by trampling over memory already allocated for other things. Literally nothing would work.

Comment: @evg you don't need to worry about phsyical memory at all.

Comment: and there are atoms between the atoms that store the bits in your chips

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Apologies, I hadn't meant to ask multiple questions, nor was I under the impression that "an [os] trampling over memory already allocated for other things" happens, but rather my intention was to better convey what I was asking; what mechanism is in place preventing memory collision with a dynamically allocated data type.

Comment: By definition if your OS allocates memory without trampling over existing allocations, then that _is_ the mechanism, no? This is a fundamental principle of a memory manager. That's its job. It's like you're asking which mechanism makes cooking produce cooked food. The answer is.. cooking! Anyway, glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are these answers?

1. The OS does (or whoever is handling your memory allocations). Usually the default allocators for vectors and strings call the OS to allocate memory on the heap. (very small strings may go on the stack with the "small string optimisation, < ~16byte strings). The OS ensures that these don't clash.
2. Yes, the standard guarantees contiguous memory for vector.
3. No, it will request the size block it needs and the OS (or whatever allocator) will provide one or fail. Defrag is an OS task.

EDIT: what @parktomatomi says is correct. `std::vector<T>` allocates enough memory for say 8 elements to begin with, then for the 9th they will re-request for 16 elements, copy everything over and free the 8 element block.Same again at 32 elements etc. The boundaries are implementation depentdant, but it's something like that. You can use `std::vector.reserve()` to avoid the re-allocate and copy process. Only usually worth it if you have perfect info, otherwise just leaving it to the doubling algorithm is usually fine.

`std::array<T, N>` is fixed sized and **stack allocated** just like primitve types (int, double etc). So it's limited in size by the stack.

Stack also doesn't clobber (obviously), because it "moves the stack pointer down into new space" with each variable declaration.

Typical stack sizes on modern desktop/server machines are 8MB on linux/OSX and 1MB on Windows. These can be adjusted. Heap sizes (where vectors go) are limited only by physical memory in the machine (in fact virtual memory if you don't mind swapping to disk). So typically several GB.

This is not a bad article on the subject. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm

But be aware that it talks a lot about `new` and `delete`. 99% of the time you should not be using those. They will happen a "automatically" inside the implementation of the `std::vector` constructor and destructor (and a few more places).

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you for a direct and concise answer. Apparently the fact I wasn't under the impression that memory _would_ be over written but rather what the mechanism is preventing it from happening didn't come through.

Comment: @CodyB I understood what you meant. Did my answer make it clear why we don't get "clobber"?

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<T>` allocates memory at runtime. The OS gives it a big block of memory that is somewhere else in the address space, and `std::vector` only holds a pointer (address) to it, so `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is always some fixed size and will not overrun the next thing on the stack.

When you push back enough elements, implementations of `std::vector` usually allocates a whole new memory buffer, and copies over all the old memory. That way, the memory stays contiguous even if it runs of room in its buffer. This incurs a small penalty for growing vectors element by element, so if you know the size it will be, `my_vector.reserve(N)` will make sure it has enough space for N elements without reallocating.

[`std::array<T, N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) works more like how you're thinking, like a C array where all the memory is part of the object. Because of this, `std::array` can't be resized.